# Сложить все значения списка включая вложенные кортежи

Tags: python

Как сложить все значения например вот такого списка [(5, 6, 7), 5], желательно не перебирая все значения в цикле, так как может быть еще и вложенный картеж например [(5, (6, 5), 7), 5], степень вложенности может быть разная. Функция sum не работает? Получается только переводить список в строку, очищать от скобок и запятых потом назад все в список и суммировать? Или есть другой способ?

Comment: Использовать рекурсивную функцию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы разделил работу на две части: обход элементов и суммирование. `traverse` - функция-генератор, которая обходит все элементы на всех уровнях. Нужна проверка можно ли итерировать элемент, нужна рекурсия для вложенных контейнеров. В остальном всё не сложно:

```
import collections.abc


def traverse(item):
    if isinstance(item, collections.abc.Iterable):
        for i in item:
            yield from traverse(i)
    else:
        yield item
```

[sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) считает сумму любой последовательности. `sum(traverse(...))` сложит все элементы, которые отыщет внутри `...`:

```
print(sum(traverse([(5, (6, 5), 7), 5])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без рекурсии со стеком и циклами. Работает с любой вложенностью tuple, list, set. Суммирует только int и float, строки игнорирует.

```
t = (1, (2.34, [5, 7], (2, 4, {1, 2, 3, 'ABC'})))
stack, summa = [t], 0
while stack:
    el = stack.pop(0)
    if isinstance(el, (tuple, list, set)):
        for i in el:
            stack.append(i)
    elif isinstance(el, (int, float)):
        summa += el
print(summa)
```

```
27.34
```